# Question regarding percentage

Tags: percentages

Imagine two persons talking .
One said my height is 10% more than yours.

If the height of 2nd person is 100cm , then the height of 1st person is 110cm.

But here: if I got 42% marks which is 12% more than passing marks , then did I get 112% of passing marks or I got 12% of total marks more than passing marks?

What is the difference between 1st and 2nd scenario?

Pls clear my misconception.

Comment: The difference between percentage and [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point).

Comment: First figure out what the passing score is. Then, figure out what percentage of that score is $42\%$.

Comment: Let passing score be 30 marks.

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari If the passing score is $30$ marks and you got $42\%$ marks, then you got less than $1$ mark and were far below the passing score...

Comment: You got a $42$ and the passing score was a $30$. How much more did you score? What percentage is that of $30$, the passing score?